# Copy/Paste of features into existing PostGIS table

Tags: qgis, postgis

I am trying to copy and paste point features from one table to an existing PostGIS table, but I get a NOT NULL, Unique error for the id field (below).  How can I update the PostGIS table with new data created in QGIS?

QGIS version
3.22.4-Białowieża

[image]

Comment: This is a bug https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/46467 there is a solution but you don't give us the version of QGIS you are using.

Comment: @Mapperz QGIS version 3.22.4-Białowieża.  I tried the solution above and it works only if I manually enter the same id value that is in the id column.

Comment: @MJM have you ticked the boxes 'Automatically create transaction groups ...' and 'Evaluate defaukt values on provider side' in the project properties / Data sources ?

Comment: Is your id column set up as a serial using a sequence?  If not, there's no 'next id' to get from the db so it will always be null.

Comment: @dd_a yes I have ticked both boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it, from the postgis side, is to add a new serial column and set it as the primary key:

```
alter table your_table add column pk serial primary key;
```

This will provide QGIS the next sequence value as the pk when you add new features.

You can also alter your existing id column like this:

```
create sequence your_table_id_seq;
alter table your_table alter column id set default nextval('your_table_id_seq');
select max(id) + 1 from your_table; -- use this value in the next part
alter sequence your_table_id_seq 
  minvalue 100 -- change this number to the max(id) + 1 value
  start 100 -- also change this number
  restart 100 -- and this number
```

You might also need to make the id column the primary key:

```
alter table your_table add primary key (id);
```